# How to cut off a part of message in Logstash

Tags: logstash

I've some micro services, which are deployed with Docker. They send their logs to my Logstash with the log driver `syslog`. Here is the config of my Logstash:

```
input {
  syslog {
    port => 9771
    type => "syslog"
  }
}

filter {
}

output {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/logstash/%{+YYYY-MM-dd}/logstash-%{+HH}.log"
  }
  if "www.envoyproxy.io" in [message] {
    file {
      path => "/var/log/logstash/%{+YYYY-MM-dd}/test-%{+HH}.log"
      codec => line { format => "%{message}" }
    }
  }
}
```

I can see logs in the file `test-01.log` like this:

```
<30>Mar  8 11:42:45 2867370d06d5[8119]: 172.16.0.226,48982,envoy,2023-03-08T03:42:39.340Z,34.142.199.10,443,-,www.envoyproxy.io,HTTP/1.1,GET,/,HTTP/1.1,200,17304,2023-03-08T03:42:39.340Z,17304,-,-,curl/7.29.0,-,1000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

I want to remove the part `<30>Mar  8 11:42:45 2867370d06d5[8119]:` before writing the logs into the file `test-01.log` but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the Logstash grok filter ([docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html)) to your pipeline, to extract the message part and remove the unwanted prefix before writing it to the output file. For example:

```
filter {
  if "www.envoyproxy.io" in [message] {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{GREEDYDATA}\]: %{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
    }
  }
}
```